# Unnatural sort of PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array in PHP that is simply strings. These strings represent relationships that can occur between different distances of family. It looks like this:

```
0 => 'Unknown',
1 => 'Parent',
2 => 'Grandparent',
3 => 'Sibling',
4 => 'Child',
5 => 'Grandchild',
6 => 'Spouse',
7 => 'Self',
9 => 'Step Parent',
10 => 'Step Sibling',
11 => 'Step Child',
etc...
```

This array works great, but I'm running into a problem where I would like to be able to sort these items in a purely custom way (specifically closer-to-father away starting with Spouse/Sibling ending with most distant relations like X-in-law), but I also would like the list to be added to over time. My initial thought was to simply order them as they needed to be ordered in the array, but that does not allow me to add relations at a later date (though it's doubtful this would ever happen, I'd rather be safe than sorry). The best solution I could come up with (an seemingly a good one in my mind) was to make a simple PHP object that would hold both the name of the relation and an arbitrary "sort" value like this `new Relation('Unknown', 0);`. The problem is, it appears that you cannot instantiate objects while making an array with the `X => Y` syntax, as I have syntax errors when I try to write this:

```
    0 => new Relation('Unknown', 0),
    1 => new Relation('Grandparent', 1),
    etc...
```

Is there a way that this could work or possibly a better solution? It seems at this point I may have to generate the array the first time it is requested (in a getter) using Array pushes then store it, but I'd rather have it nicely formatted. Am I just out of luck?

Edit - To clarify: The keys right now are being used as the stored value in the database. In essence, we are using the array as an enum in other languages.

Comment: Your syntax looks fine to me, and works: http://codepad.org/gfdjDXp9 You probably have an unrelated error.

Comment: Yep, you should be able to instantiate objects in arrays without a problem. Try something like  0 => (new Relation('Unknown', 0))

Comment: Maybe I simply shouldn't trust Netbeans so much, it changes the entire file red when you try this syntax, which is rather annoying, but I suppose I should have tested it server-side before posting, I will attempt it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the array as a map, such as relationship_name => relationship_distance.  If it is more convenient, you can do relationship_distance => relationship_name.  Make the relationship_distance values arbitrary, with gaps in between so that intermediate distances can be added later.  For example:

```
'Sibling' => 1,
'Parent' => 10,
'Grandparent' => 20,
'Greatgrandparent' => 30,
'Uncle' => 13,
'BrotherInLaw' => 17,
```

Then you can sort the map by they keys or the values and add new entries as needed.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, but I should have clarified. The keys right now are being used as the stored value in the database. In essence, we are using the array as an enum in other languages. I will still look into using this as an option as well though, thank you.

Comment: I would separate the two concepts.  One is a mapping to relationship distance and the other is a mapping to the enum value for storage.  You can put them both in the same structure if you wish 1 => array('distance' => 10, 'name' => 'parent'), ...  But it is sometimes better to have separate mappings.

Comment: That is actually a great idea... What I think I will end up doing is making a second array that maps the relation names to their sort values, and is private to the class, my sorting function can then use that and keep it invisible to outside the class... Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You could write this in a array. What happens to be a syntax error is if you wrote that in a class property.

You can't do this:

```
class A {
  public $relations = array(
    0 => new Relation('Unknown', 0),
    1 => new Relation('Grandparent', 1)
  );
}
```

But you could do the init in the constructor.

```
class A {
   public $relations;
   public function __construct() {
      $this->relations = array(
         0 => new Relation('Unknown', 0),
         1 => new Relation('Grandparent', 1)
      );
   }
}
```

***PS:*** if the keys is just 0,1,... you could omit them.

Comment: That was the problem! We were attempting to write it as a property in a class, moving it the constructor is just fine with me so I will do that. Thanks for the tip about indices as well, some of the coders here simply enjoy being explicit.

Comment: Another thing I suppose I forgot, and the reason it was a property, we wanted this to be static so we wouldn't need an instance to see it, but since it actually IS a syntax error I may be out of luck again.